# I am not able to compile my code in typescript

Tags: typescript2.0

tsc : File C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. And I am using Visual Studio

Comment: Is it your organization laptop or desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Guys I did this and it worked:

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted